# What do I need to do to get cocoapods to build with C++?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, cocoapods

I'm trying to build a library to distribute via Cocoapods. The library is written mainly in Objective C, but includes a few C++ files. None of the C++ headers are part of the library's public API. The library builds fine in Xcode, and I can distribute as a framework, but a pod is probably easier for others to consume, right?

This is my first time attempting to build a cocoapod, so I may be doing something obviously wrong.

When I run `pod lib lint` or try to build the demo app that depends on the pod, I get error messages that suggest that the build system doesn't understand C++ at all.

*in a C++ header file:*

```
class CGuard {
> unknown type name 'class'; did you mean 'Class'?
```

*in another C++ header file:*

```
template<typename T>
class CContexts {
> unknown type name 'template'
```

My podspec file includes

```
spec.xcconfig = {
  'CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD' => 'c++11',
  'CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY' => 'libc++'
}
spec.library = "c++"
```

What else can I do to tell the build system to use the C++ compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the key was adding `private_header_files` entries to remove the C++ headers from the framework that Cocoapods exports.

Although Cocoapods is documented to only include the files from `public_header_files` in the generated module umbrella header, it looks like each `subspec` section has all of its headers included if that `subspec` section doesn't have its own `public_header_files` entry.

The C++ files were all compiled in a `subspec` section to let me use different compiler settings, so the `private_header_files` entry needed to be inside that `subspec` section as well.

Comment: after moving c++ headers to private, public OBJC headers cant include them  on compilation